# How to segue to previous screen using Swift without losing data in swift 4

Tags: swift, segue

I have a button from my create account page that opens up another view controller that has some information in it. 
i move it by doing a segue:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "sugueToRules", sender: self)
```

on my other Viewcontroller i have a back button that connects form the storyboard, to the create account one (the precious one)

when i go back i lose all my data that i put on the create account, 
so i must open a new instance of it.

how do i keep all my data of it when i go back ? 
do i have to save a local file somewhere and load it when i come back ?

i'm using swift 4

Comment: Make sure that they are managed by a `UINavigationController`. Then the back button will do its job just fine. Right now it appears that you are allocating a new controller each time you go back. The same applies to a modally presented controller, although you have to `dismiss` (or use an exit segue) instead of firing up a segue pointing back. I hope that this makes sense.

Comment: @Alladinian great answer, put it as an answer and i'll accept it

Comment: @ChiefMadog Done. Glad that helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that they are managed by a `UINavigationController`. Then the back button will do its job just fine (no need for you to 'wire' something -- this is the default behaviour). Right now it appears that you are allocating a new controller each time you go back.

The same applies to a modally presented controller (with a custom close button for example), although you have to dismiss (or use an exit segue) instead of firing up a segue pointing back.

Answer (score 1):

Passing segue to previous screen will creates a new instance of the previous viewcontroller. It it better to be bound in navigation controller and popout the presented screen using when back navigation is not required.

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use UINavigationController  for navigating UIViewController like -

[image]